# Minecraft cannot connect to server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Whenever I try to connect to a server (only in the modpack SkyFactory 3, usually Minecraft connects ok) the game gives me this error: "Failed to login: Invalid Session (Try restarting your game)".

Comment: Did you try restarting your game?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried restarting your game? (Just close out of Minecraft and start it up again)

If that doesn't work, trying logging out of your account from the launcher, then signing in again.